# Bayesian network exact inference

Tags: inference, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

Could someone please write step-by-step solution to get $P(D|L,B)$ ($P(D=true|L=true,B=true)$) by exact inference? I tried variable elimination but I am getting some weird numbers and I want to check how it should be done properly.

[image]